# Setting html document width to fit text

Tags: html, css, width

I have an html document that is included as an iframe in a toolbar. The document includes a single line of text.

I wish to limit the width of the document, so that it doesn't exceed a maximal width, but can occupy less if the text is short.

How can this be achieved?

If helpful, the document is actually a php document and I can use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the maximum width is given in pixels, I’d style the inluded document via CSS:

```
body {
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Note: this does not work in IE6, as it does not support the `max-width` property.

Apart from that, since you can use JavaScript, instead of using an `iframe` you could also fetch the HTML via AJAX and inject the document into the DOM—which should make for easier/better styling.